# Not able to create Basic MSI Project from InstallShieldProjects in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-2013

I have Installed InstallShield 2013 for Visual Studio 2013 .It asked for installation of Service Pack 1.Which I have installed. Now while adding the project templates it says "project xyz unable to create" . As I am new to this , I am not able to get where I am going wrong. Please help

Comment: Its Visual Studio 2013 - typing error!

Comment: You can always edit your question @skb

Comment: look at [**this**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) addon by microsoft, it brings back the simple installer project that we all know and love..